# How to insert multiple rows at once in core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, ios5

How to insert multiple rows with a single operation? I don't want to use loop to insert data. I would insert data with a single query. Is there any way in Core Data to insert multiple rows together?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to loop?!?

Answer (score 3):

In Core Data one `NSManagedObject` can be considered as having information related to one row, for multiple row you need to create that many `NSManagedObject`. Hence, without loop you can't achieve inserting multiple rows.